# Where does this formula come from "initial velocity to achieve some height"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

lets say a fountain shoots water at some height $y$ then why the formula relating the initial velocity of water at the base that is required to achieve that height is:

$$\frac{1}{2}V_0^2 = g(y - y_0).$$

where does this formula came from how it is derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conservation of energy is a uniform gravitational field, the initial kinetic energy is totally converted to potential energy at the maximum height.

Comment: and why is that : $$\frac{1}{2}v^2 = \frac{1}{2}v_0^2-g(y-y_0)$$?

Comment: From either the conservation of energy, or as @Ken Mellendorf states from motion in one direction at constant acceleration a = -g.  See any basic physics textbook.

Answer (score 1):

This formula assumes acceleration is constant and in one dimension: $a$.  The calculus relationships and some algebra can find one of the standard constant-acceleration kinematic equations derived in any physics textbook.  The situation you describe is one-dimensional, so we don't need to deal with vector components.  Up is positive.

$v^2-v_0^2 =2a(y-y_0)$

At the top, $v=0$.  Acceleration is downward, so $a=-g$.  The rest is just rearranging things to look like your formula.

Answer (score 1):

That formula is showing how the kinetic energy of the water as it shoots up is equal to the potential energy that the water has at the top of its path. Energy is conserved.
$KE$=$(1/2)mv^2$ (kinetic energy) and $PE$=$mgh$ (this is basically gravitational potential for near Earth's surface) are used in this setup, where the maximum $KE$ equals the maximum $PE$. Also, $h$ (height) is the $y-y_0$ here.

$E_1$=$E_2$
$KE_(max)$=$PE_(max)$
$(1/2)mv^2$=$mg(y-y_0)$
$(1/2)v^2$=$g(y-y_0)$

(The $m$'s canceled out.)